# Nginx Global server block?

Tags: nginx

How can I define a server block that applies to all virtual hosts?

Aka have a universal block to configure SSL for all subdomains (they use the same cert)

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Have a block like this that does SSL for all subdomains
server {
    listen          443 ssl ;
    listen          [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name         *.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /certs/live/example.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /certs/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple `server` blocks that use common configuration, many `nginx` directives can be placed in the outer block (`http { ... }`) and will be inherited by any `server` block that does not specifically override the values. Notice the *Context:* when checking an `nginx` directive. See [the list of directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).

Alternatively, use the `include` directive to pull common configuration statements from an external file into any part of the configuration file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

Comment: +1 for the include, imho it is the preferred way to go as not all directives can be placed in the `server` block, on top of that, you can use variables to substitute common strings in includes, which enables templating for automation